# Bound of functional $g(0) - 7g(\frac12)$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let's consider functional

$$f\colon (C[0,1], \Vert\cdot \Vert_\infty) \ni g\rightarrow g(0) - 7g(\frac12)$$

I'm trying to judge whether functional $f$ is bounded or not, however I'm dealing with problems of interpretation of condition to consider.

We want to check whether there is some ball that $f$ will be inside it.

But I'm not sure how exactly this ball will look in this space

In my opinion it should look like following:

$$B(C[0,1], r) = \{h \in C[0,1] : \lVert f-h \rVert < r\}$$

But I'm not sure if it's true. Could you please tell me if I'm thinking correctly, or maybe this ball looks differently in this space?

Comment: bounded iff continuous, and point evaluations are continuous and so are linear combinations of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $g \in V = (\mathcal C([0,1], \mathbb R)$ you have

$$\vert f(g) \vert = \left\vert g(0) - 7 g\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \right\vert \le \Vert g \Vert_\infty + 7 \Vert g \Vert_\infty = 8 \Vert g \Vert_\infty.$$

This proves that $f$ is bounded: for $\Vert g \Vert_\infty \le 1$, you have $\vert f(g) \vert \le 8$. As $f$ is linear, you immediately get for $g,h \in V$

$$\vert f(h) - f(g) \vert \le 8 \Vert h - g \Vert_\infty.$$

Even more, the norm of $f$ is equal to $8$ as for the map $h(x)=\vert 4x - 2 \vert -1$ we have $\Vert h \Vert_\infty = 1$ and $f(h)=8$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I just have some questions about the formality of your justification. How did you get that $f$ is linear (becuase it''s a sum of two real numbers) ? Could you please explain me how from linearity of $f$ you get $|f(h) - |f(g)| \le 8 \Vert h - g \Vert$ ?

Comment: Also more extended explanation why norm of $f$ equals 8 would be appriciated (I'm not exactly sure how it came from calculation of norm for $h$)

Comment: About linearity, just apply the linearity axioms. $f(g+h)=f(g)+f(h)$...  For the norm of $f$ (Take care that we’re speaking of the norm of the functional here!)., we have a map of norm (the other one!) equal to one while the norm of its image (a third norm, the absolute value of the reals) is equal to $8$. This is sufficient to conclude.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g \in C([0,1])$ be arbitrary and let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then we have:
$$
|f(g)-f(h)|=|g(0)-7g(0.5)+h(0)-7h(0.5)| \leq |g(0)-h(0)|+|7g(0.5)-7h(0.5)| \leq \\
||g-h||_{\infty}+7||g-h||_{\infty}=8||g-h||_{\infty}<^! \epsilon
$$
So if we choose $||g-h||_{\infty} < \frac{\epsilon}{8}=\delta$, we have checked the epsilon-delta definition of continuity using open balls. You then have
$$
f(B_{\delta}(g)) \subset B_{\epsilon}(f(g))
$$
A short note on your notation for balls:
$$
B_r(f)=\{g \in C([0,1]) | \; ||f-g||_{\infty}<r   \}
$$
You can also use $B_r(f)=B(f,r)$ as a notation. You usually just mention the centre and the radius, not the space you are taking this ball in. However, you can or even have to denote it somewhere in your text/question/whatever.